# What is the physical interpretation of the linear coefficient in this ODE for projectile motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag, oscillators, dissipation

For the second order ODE governing the position of a projectile subject to air resistance

$$ m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} +k\frac{dx}{dt}+mg=0 \quad k>0, \> x(0)=0, \> x'(0)=V>0 $$

a non-dimensionalization can me made so that the system is then

$$ \frac{d^2X}{d\tau^2} +\beta\frac{dX}{d\tau}+1=0 \quad k>0 $$

for non-dimensional variables $X,\tau$. It turns out $ \beta=\frac{kV}{mg}$.  What is the physical interpretation of $\beta$?  I was inclined to say that it is the terminal velocity, but examining the ODE shows that terminal velocity is actually $\frac{mg}{k}$.  I know that $\beta$ is the ratio between the the resistance it feels when fired and the total downward force.

So the question remains: What is $\beta$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost answered it on your own!

Essentially it's the ratio of the viscous force to the gravitational force. As $\beta \rightarrow 0$, the gravitational force dominates and the damping due to air friction is very small. Likewise, as $\beta \rightarrow \infty$, the air friction dominates the solution.

This isn't really all that illustrative physically, but it doesn't always have to be. What it does allow you do to is use only $\beta$ to determine trends. For example, if $\beta = 0.5$, the solution is the same whether you are on Mars, or under water on Earth, or your mass is huge or small, etc.. It's a *similiarity* parameter that reduces the number of variables in your problem from 4 ($k$, $V$, $m$, $g$) to a single variable, $\beta$.